# Problems on Schwartz Functions

Tags: functions, fourier-analysis, harmonic-analysis

(1) What are all positive Schwartz Functions on $\mathbb R$  whose Fourier Transform is positive ?

(2) What are all Schwartz Functions on $\mathbb R$  whose Fourier Transform is positive ?

(3) What are all positive Schwartz Functions on $\mathbb R$  whose Fourier Transform is non-negative ?

(4) What are all Schwartz Functions on $\mathbb R$  whose Fourier Transform is non-negative ?

Answer (score 3):

**Reference:** [On positive functions with positive Fourier transforms](http://arxiv.org/pdf/math-ph/0504015v1.pdf) develops a basis of functions which are positive along with their Fourier Transforms. In $\mathbb{R}$ the results are built from Hermite Polynomials and in $\mathbb{R}^2$ from radial Laguerre Polynomials.